# How to edit tiff metadata in R?

Tags: gdal, r, metadata, geotiff-tiff, rgdal

I would like to edit the metadata attributes of an tiff file. In particular the TIFFTAG attributes as described [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html).

In Python it's a piece of cake:

```python
from osgeo import gdal  
ras = gdal.Open('test.tif', gdal.GA_Update)  
ras.SetMetadataItem('TIFFTAG_DATETIME', '2016:08:12 13:00:41')  
ras = None
```

Or you just use `gdal_edit.py`:

```bash
gdal_edit.py -mo TIFFTAG_DATETIME='2016:08:12 13:00:41' test.tif
```

Up until Version 0.5.27 `rgdal` seemed to have functions available for this (see [here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/0.5-26/topics/GDALMajorObject-class)).

Does anyone know whether this can still be done?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that currently R doesn't support gdal metadata tagging. The function you are looking for does no longer exist in `rgdal` and possibly have been deprecated. You may also notice that the `setMetaData` function was defined as a method of the `GDALMajorObject-class` (see [here](http://ftp.auckland.ac.nz/software/CRAN/doc/packages/rgdal.pdf), p. 6). Currently however there are no methods associated with this class (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/rgdal.pdf), p. 10).

There is one option to write metadata to a GTiff using R. Yet, it is restricted to the file description, using `rtiff::updateDescription()`.

> Sets the TIFF description field (tag 270) for a TIFF file.

See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtiff/rtiff.pdf), p. 8. You need an updateDate() for tag 306.

Basically, there is no way to setMetaData in R, yet a work around may involve XML manipulations on the `...aux.xml` file. You can write this file with the `writeRaster(..., options = "PROFILE=GeoTIFF")`. For my opinion it doesn't worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out here! I'll try to get in touch with the package developers and see whether they have any suggestions.